# SWFObject embedded Flash fullscreen doesn't work on PC

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, fullscreen, swfobject

I created a fullscreen flash app on
http://dominggus.nl/school/afstuderen/expo/

I used the SWFObject generator to create the embedding code.
Furthermore, I need to put the screen.width/screen.height (with JavaScript) as flashVars to the SWF...

This all works perfectly on MAC on Chrome/FF but, on windows it only works in IE...chrome and Firefox refuse to go fullscreen...

how can that be?

edit: I already tried static/dynamic publishing with SWFObject, same results
(see http://dominggus.nl/school/afstuderen/expo/index2.html for dynamic)

Comment: I would check the javascript error console on FF and Chrome and see if it's throwing any errors/warnings when you load up the page in Windows.  Both FF and Chrome use the Netscape-like plugin whereas IE uses ActiveX plugin, I'm not too familiar with SWFObject though I know it generally deals with the browser differences for embedding a swf in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah looks like you're running into a flash run-time error but not seeing it in Chrome or FF cause of no Debug player installed, this is easy for FF just install the netscape compatible debug player to see the error (for Chrome the install is more complicated, due to it managing Flash player updates internally).

In FF I get this error:

SecurityError: Error #2152: Full screen mode is not allowed.
    at flash.display::Stage/set displayState()
    at nl.dominggus.infographic.ui::NoFullScreenPage/startButtonClickHandler()[/Users/dominggus/Documents/dpdk/eclipse_workspace/cmd_afstuderen_infographic/src/as/nl/dominggus/infographic/ui/NoFullScreenPage.as:54]

I believe this means the allowFullscreen parameter for the plugin isn't being set correctly.

Verify Flash player version here (bottom of page shows debug Yes/No):
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html

Get the appropriate Debug player for a given platform:
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

**Edit** pasted from the docs

FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE Constant
public static const FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE:String = "fullScreenInteractive"
Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0
Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 11.3, AIR 1.0, Flash Lite 4

Comment: hmm seems like StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE doesn't work correctly on some browsers. I needed the keyboard support for debugging purposes...
it now works like a charm! AWESOME! thanks shaun

Comment: Ah okay, it may have something to do with the FlashPlayer version, the full screen interactive is only available in FP 11.3 though normally I wouldn't expect an error, generally things are backwards compatible to some degree, adding a new event dispatch or something of the sort shouldn't cause an error, but might be just a rare case.